# JQ: convert value into nested key-value object

Tags: json, jq

I am lost with an easy-looking JQ problem. Given a key-value object, I want to transform the value into a nested object with a "value"-key. I tried permutations with 'to_entries' and native output as well as the {}-output option, but without success. I'm convinced that there is a rather obvious solution, but I cannot find it.

Input:

`{ "mykey" : "myvalue" }`

Desired output:

`{ "mykey" : { "value" : "myvalue" }}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ jq '{(keys[0]): {value:.[keys[0]]}} ' <<< '{ "mykey" : "myvalue" }'

{
  "mykey": {
    "value": "myvalue"
  }
}
```